# Batch Created Folder By Filename Part and Move

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, dir, findstr

I found magoo's post and been playing around with it.  I can't seem to get the DIR part to parse out the file name to create the folder and move the files to the respective folders.  The following are examples of the files I'm working with:

```
...
800.1.gif
800.2.gif
800.3.jpg
801.1.gif
801.2.jpg
801.3.gif
...
```

The batch should create folders 800 and 801 and move the 800.X and 801.X files respectively.  I've tried FINDSTR and other masks and not having much luck.

Here's magoo's original batch code (source: http://bit.ly/1ua8IIF):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*_*_*-*-* *.*"'
 ) DO (  
 ECHO MD %%a
 ECHO MOVE "%%a %%b" .\%%a\
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

My attempt after a few hours:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d ^|findstr /r "\.[1-9]"'
 ) DO (  
 ECHO MD %%a
 ECHO MOVE "%%a %%b" .\%%a\
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

I'm still playing around with it but any help would be greatly appreciated it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifications you'd need to make are:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=." %%a IN (
```

Adding the `delims=.` means "treat `.` as a delimiter." In the original, the default delimiter <kbd>Space</kbd> was used.

```
 'dir /b /a-d "*.*.gif" "*.*.jpg"'
```

Perform the directory list on files matching `*.*.gif` or `*.*.jpg`

The quotes are unnecessary but harmless. In the original, the filemask needed to have the space included in the mask string; space is a separator and quoting the string removes the special meaning.

This would match any file matching either extension. If you want to match any file of the pattern `*.*.*` then feel free to change this to

```
 'dir /b /a-d *.*.*'
```

finally,

```
 ECHO MOVE "%%a.%%b" .\%%a\
```

It's simply a matter of rebuilding the original string by re-inserting the `.` parsed out by the `for` - in this case `.` but in the original <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much.  I just found out about delims.  This would've saved me more time instead of fiddling with FINDSTR regex's - ugh!  Thanks, again, Magoo!